# Laravel - File Input Array Update

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I want  to update my file input images, but as soon as I update 1 image the other images are removed why is that? I want to left them as what they are when they had been upload. help me please thanks.

[Here is an image of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f4mRr.png)

***Controller***

Update, public function, here is where I put the logic of the code

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
          $this->validate($request, [
        'inflightmagz_date' => 'required',
        'infightmagazine_pdf.*' => 'image|nullable|max:1999'
    ]);

    $inflightmags = [];

    if ($request->has('infightmagazine_pdf'))
    {   
        //Handle File Upload


        foreach ($request->file('infightmagazine_pdf') as $key => $file)
        {
            // Get FileName
            $filenameWithExt = $file->getClientOriginalName();
            //Get just filename
            $filename = pathinfo( $filenameWithExt, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
            //Get just extension
            $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
            //Filename to Store
            $fileNameToStore = $filename.'_'.time().'.'.$extension;
            //Upload Image
            $path = $file->storeAs('public/infightmagazine_pdfs',$fileNameToStore);
            array_push($inflightmags, $fileNameToStore);
        }

        $fileNameToStore = serialize($inflightmags);
    }



    $inflightmagContent =  InflightMagazine::find($id);
    $inflightmagContent->inflightmagz_date = $request->input('inflightmagz_date');
       foreach ($inflightmags as $key => $value) {

        $implodedInflight = implode(' , ', $inflightmags);
        if($request->hasFile('infightmagazine_pdf')){
        $inflightmagContent->infightmagazine_pdf = $implodedInflight;
        }

    }
    $inflightmagContent->save();
    return redirect('/admin/airlineplus/inflightmagazines')->with('success', 'Content Updated');
}
```

***View, edit.blade.php***

```
  {!! Form::open(['action'=>['Admin\FleetsController@update',$fleet->id], 'method' => 'POST','enctype'=>'multipart/form-data', 'name' => 'add_name', 'id' => 'add_name']) !!}

        <div class="table-responsive">
          <table class="table table-bordered" id="dynamic_field">
            <tr>
              <td>   {{Form::text('title', $fleet->title, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Enter a Title', 'id'=>"exampleFormControlFile1"])}}<br>

                {{Form::textarea('description', $fleet->description, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Enter a Description'])}} <br>
                <div class="card card-body col-md-8">

                @foreach(explode(' , ' ,$fleet->fleet_image) as $content)
                  <img src="{{ asset('storage/fleet_images/' . $content) }}" style="width:50px;height:50px;"><br/>

                  {{ Form::file('fleet_image[]',['id'=>'exampleFormControlFile1']) }}<br/>
                  @endforeach 
                </div>
             </td>

            </tr>
          </table>
          {{Form::hidden('_method', 'PUT')}}
          {{Form::submit('submit', ['class'=>'btn btn-primary', 'name'=>'submit'])}}
        </div>
    {!! Form::close() !!}
```

Comment: b'cause you upload only one image and another two image empty so its update as empty thats why you two image are update as empty. So for that you need to check if image has empty value than no update and keep its old value at it is.

Comment: How can i do that? nice logic sir. how is the syntax? can u pls edit my code sir pls i badly need for this to work

Comment: check `hasFile` inside for loop

Comment: can you please edit my code sir :( so you can let me upvote and marked your answer please :(

Answer (score 0):

try this code

add if condition like `if($request->hasFile('infightmagazine_pdf') && !empty($implodedInflight) && isset($implodedInflight))` this

```
//Handle File Upload
foreach ($request->file('infightmagazine_pdf') as $key => $file)
{
    if ($file->has('infightmagazine_pdf'))
    {  
        // Get FileName
        $filenameWithExt = $file->getClientOriginalName();
        //Get just filename
        $filename = pathinfo( $filenameWithExt, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
        //Get just extension
        $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
        //Filename to Store
        $fileNameToStore = $filename.'_'.time().'.'.$extension;
        //Upload Image
        $path = $file->storeAs('public/infightmagazine_pdfs',$fileNameToStore);
        array_push($inflightmags, $fileNameToStore);
        $fileNameToStore = serialize($inflightmags);
    }
} 

$inflightmagContent =  InflightMagazine::find($id);
    $inflightmagContent->inflightmagz_date = $request->input('inflightmagz_date');
       foreach ($inflightmags as $key => $value) {

        $implodedInflight = implode(' , ', $inflightmags);
        if($request->hasFile('infightmagazine_pdf') && !empty($implodedInflight) && isset($implodedInflight)){
        $inflightmagContent->infightmagazine_pdf = $implodedInflight;
        }

    }
    $inflightmagContent->save();
    return redirect('/admin/airlineplus/inflightmagazines')->with('success', 'Content Updated');
```

Comment: still the same sir :( it does not work :( i insert two images and when i update it removed the other image :(

Comment: print your `$fileNameToStore` array outside the `for loop` and see what was the result

Comment: wait . it throws an error saying .. **Method Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile::has does not exist.**

Comment: hehe sorry i dont know the syntax for print pls tell me :)

Comment: `echo "<pre>;print_r(array);"`

Comment: i think your code was not correct? and didnt understand your array structure

Comment: No sir, it is correct, when I copy your code it throws an error which is **Method Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile::has does not exist.**

Comment: so why you do this `$fileNameToStore = serialize($inflightmags);` this variable never use on your code

Comment: and what reason behind this `$implodedInflight = implode(' , ', $inflightmags);`

Comment: i implode it because i need the images to be stored in one ROW in my database

Comment: so what its value every time when loop ?

Comment: @obitouchiha i uodate my answer use `if condtion` on your existing code

Comment: Oh should i remove the `if($request->has('inflightmagazine_pdf'))` before the foreach loop?

Comment: @Bgargav Chudasama , sir, this error is really occuring idk why **Method Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile::has does not exist.**

Comment: Not use My code use your own code and just change if condition only bro

Comment: Not yet bro, I tried to change some condition still nothing works :(